# Link xml lay-out with java class

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-studio

```
package com.example.bjorn.guidbru;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Extra_Info {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra_info, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I am new with android studio and I have to create a simple app.
I made a class `Extra_Info` and also the XML lay-out file `extra_info`.
Now I want to show the content of the file in the XML in my app using this code.
But it doesn't works. 
What do I have to add?

I am using `navigationdrawer` activity.

Comment: You need to extend your class.

Comment: but from which other class? From the navigationdrawer?

Comment: I don't know what you exactly want in your question, but I think you need to read this: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: I have now a blanco page. Just the background color. But i made layout-xml but i don't know to which class i have to extend to show it.